# NDSolve to solve a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

How to edit the code in the picture?

And the equation system is 
dx/dt = x (2 − 0.4 x − 0.3 y)
dy/dt = y (1 − 0.1 y − 0.3 x) 
With given initial value is 
x[0]=1.5 and y[0]=3.5

Comment: Please, post the code in editable form. This would allows us play with it which is often necessary to figure out the problem. Back to your question: There is `xy` appearing multiple times. I have the feeling that you meant to have `x[t] y[t]` (equivalently `x[t] * y[t]`) there.

Comment: Notice how `parametricPlot` is blue?  That means that it is not defined.  All built-in functions are capitalized, so you want `ParametricPlot` instead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE. 1) Please don't post the same question over and over, try to edit the original if you have something to add. 2) Please don't ignore comments of people trying to help you, asking another question won't help to get answer 3) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!